# Was there a talent that let you roll operate with intelligence instead of agility?

Tags: warhammer-40k, dark-heresy-2e

I'm planning out a character for a Dark Heresy 2e game, and I remember there being a talent that let you use an interface port to operate a vehicle with intelligence instead of agility if you could plug into it. I'm trying to find it but with no luck. Does anyone know what book this is in?

Answer (score 1):

This is not due to a talent, it is listed as an alternate characteristic of the operate skill (page 99 of the core rulebook (CRB)).
The rules about alternate characteristics are found on page 96 of the CRB, but to summarize, the DM may decide that a characteristic other than the default one is more appropriate in a given situation. To quote an example from the book itself:

> A faltering cogitator’s delicate repair could call on Agility
> rather than Intelligence for the Tech-Use test attempt.

Intelligence being listed in the alternate characteristics of the operate skill probably has something to do with the operate voidship specialty, since it says on page 112 in the "what is a voidship?" paragraph:

> Piloting such vessels is less about personal agility and reflexes, and more about the intelligence to make correct course decisions and select proper manoeuvres.